# How can I split multiple lines text/paragraphs into different columns in excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I got almost 2000 articles that I have to post in WordPress site through csv file. I want to delimit every article to each cell which were separated by a comma. But I'm unable to get the result as my articles have separate lines and divided into paragraphs. When I tried to delimit the data each line went into each column. I want the whole article into one column which are separated by comma(,) below you can see a example.

Example:

```
Title                 Content                           Author
My first article      Article 1 xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xx xx x xxxx xx xx
                      xx xxx xx xx xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xxxxxxxx xx xx ( , )
                      Article 2 xxx xx xxxxxx
                      xxx xx xxxxxxx xx xx
                      xxxx xxx xxxxxx xx xx,
                      Article 3 xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xx xx x xxxx xx xx
                      xx xxx xx xx xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xxxxxxxx xx xx,
```

I want something like below.

```
                      Content                           

Column 1              Article 1 xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xx xx x xxxx xx xx
                      xx xxx xx xx xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xxxxxxxx xx xx

Column 2              Article 2 xxx xx xxxxxx
                      xxx xx xxxxxxx xx xx
                      xxxx xxx xxxxxx xx xx

Coulmn 3              Article 3 xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xx xx x xxxx xx xx
                      xx xxx xx xx xxxx xx xx
                      xxx xxxxxxxx xx xx
```

Answer (score 1):

With data in **A1**, in **A2** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,",",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy down:

[image]

This formula parses data based on the ***comma***.